# Regex.Match throws FormatException

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with UDP and right now I am catching information sent out from a sensor. I am trying to extract only the numbers from the information send, which is Temperature, Light and Movement and trying to achieve that with Regex. But I am getting a FormatException that states:" Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format ". Here is the code:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(1337);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

while (true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        Byte[] receive = udpClient.Receive(ref endPoint);
        string receiveDat = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive);
        string result = Regex.Match(receiveDat, @"\D+").Value;

        Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(result)); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Regex.Match` does not throw that exception. Its `Int32.Parse` which throws that exception.

`\d` takes digits while `\D` takes non-digits. so change `\D+` to `\d+`.... what is `while (true)` for?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary why do you post answers in comments? I see you even posted this answer and deleted it. I think the purpose of comments is not to provide short answers, but to discuss points that don't directly provide an answer. Do you see it differently?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN thats true. but i just give answer to part of the question. if you look at loops you will notice that it is completely wrong and does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a lowercase `\d` in your regular expression if you want digits instead of non-digits. Capital `\D` matches only non-digits.